# How to create & write data in the XSLT file?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, xslt

I want to create the xslt file programmatically  by using vb.net. & i want to write some nodes & subnodes in that file .

how can i do this? can anybody help me in resolving this problem?

thanx.....

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What have you tried so far and why didn't it work?

Comment: From what you have to create provide the code that you have written

Comment: XSLT stylesheet are XML documents. I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when this requirement arises, the XSLT that you want to generate has 95% fixed (predictable) content, and 5% dynamic content. In this case the best approach is to put the fixed content in an XML file, and transform it using XSLT to generate the dynamic content.

There are other cases where the content is mainly dynamic, for example when you want to generate lots of template rules for conditions defined in some input file. In this case too generating the stylesheet using XSLT is often a useful technique.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT is nothing but xml which follow XSL namespace and predefined xsl functions. I suggest create one basic XSLT with possible outputs and use specific xml to transform into another XST file.

Here is draft code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:element name ="stylesheet" namespace ="xsl">
    <xsl:attribute name ="version">1.0</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name ="xsl" namespace="xmlns">http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform</xsl:attribute>

  <xsl:element name ="value-of" namespace ="xsl">

    <xsl:attribute name ="select">demo</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:element>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```